# call a random function in javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have a problem with my JavaScript code. The random thing is not working :/ What do u think whats the problem ?

I have two "slide show" but if i click on the first image to start the slide its not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

   function elso() { 
        $(".start").click(function() {
        $.when($('.start2').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
            $.when($('.start3').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                $.when($('.start4').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                    $.when($('.start5').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                        $(".start").hide();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".start").show();
                            $(".start2, .start3, .start4, .start5").hide();
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    }

       function masodik () { 
        $(".start").click(function() {
        $.when($('.start2').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
            $.when($('.start3').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                $.when($('.start4').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                    $.when($('.start5').show().delay(2000)).done(function() {
                        $(".start").hide();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".start").show();
                            $(".start2, .start3, .start4, .start5").hide(); 
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    }

 function randomFrom(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
function randomchords() {
  // add the 'window' prefix here
  randomFrom(window['elso', 'masodik'])();
}

});


  </script>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to evaluate to: window['elso', 'masodik']?  If all you are trying to do is start one of those functions, chosen at random something like:  (Math.random() < 0.5 ? masodik() : elos()) is much simpler.

Comment: Can you trim this down to a **minimal** example that demonstrates the problem? This is a little nuts, especially with your badly nested callbacks.

Comment: `Random function is not working` So... would you like to tell us which function is not working? We don't want to guess. :)

Comment: maybe a `randomFrom([elso, masodik])` would work? This is not valid js syntax: `window['elso', 'masodik']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the functions using `window` as they are not global. Besides, that would be `[window.elso, window.masodic]` or `[window['elso'], window[masodic]]` rather than `window['elso', 'masodik']`.

The functions are in scope, so you can just use their names to access them. Just make an array with the references to the functions, and pick from it:

```
function randomchords() {
  randomFrom([elso, masodik])();
}
```

Comment: http://csabaadi.com/cv/ not working :S

Comment: @pearcider: You have to call the function also.

Comment: like this ? sorry im a begginer 

`code`function randomchords() {
  // add the 'window' prefix here
  randomFrom(window['elso', 'masodik'])();
  makeArray('elso', 'masodik');  
}`code`

Comment: @pearcider: Like this: `randomchords();`

Comment: i dont get it sorry :/

Comment: @pearcider: You have a bunch of code, but it doesn't do anything because it never runs. You need a call that starts it.

Comment: yes i understand this but i cant handel this problem :/

Comment: @pearcider: Just add the call to the function after the function.